# xparse command with just optional argument fails

Tags: macros, xparse

I am trying to define a command with xparse that takes an optional argument but no mandatory argument. The optional argument is a number, which works fine with a single digit but not with more. The command is as follows:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xspace}

\NewDocumentCommand \HL { o } {\IfNoValueTF #1 {\emph{HL}\xspace}{\emph{HL} {#1}\xspace}}

\HL
(\HL[1])
(\HL[10])
```

I want the following result:

> *HL*
>
> (*HL* 1)
>
> (*HL* 10)

But I get this:

> *HL*
>
> (*HL* 1)
>
> (*HLHL* 10)

Comment: `\IfNoValueTF{#1}`: you're missing the braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `#1` is potentially more than one token you should always handle it in braces. Thus you need

```
\IfNoValueTF {#1}
```

which prevents the second or later tokens of `#1` being misunderstood as one the the true/false branches. In your case, `\HL[10]` is only testing `1` and treating the `0` as the true branch for the conditional, leading to the odd output.